# "No package glibc.i686 available" while installing glibc with yum

Tags: software-installation, yum

I try the following, but I get `No package glibc.i686 available`.
What do I need to do in order to install the glibc.i686? 
Or maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

```
 yum install glibc.i686
 Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
 Updating certificate-based repositories.
 Unable to read consumer identity
 Setting up Install Process
 No package glibc.i686 available.
```

I have Linux RedHat 6.3 ( from `uname -a` I get → `86_64`  )

Comment: can you [edit] your question to add the result of the command `uname -a` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your distro is a 64bit x86.
the package i686 will not be available in your default repository and would be probably not compatible with the other package you have installed.

You should install `glibc` for your distro.

```
yum install glibc
```

Comment: I get "Nothing to do " unable to read consumer identity

Comment: @Eytan then it's already install

Comment: please refer to my next question - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123905/linux-lib-ld-linux-so-2-bad-elf-interpreter-cisco-vpn-client

Comment: the next question is part of the problem

Comment: I think that glibc is almost always install your problem here, is not being able to explain your problem maybe, because I do not sere anywhere in your other ost that you need glibc